# Eliminar objeto de un array *ngFor (Angular) drag and drop

Tags: array, angular, javascript-objeto, drag-and-drop, ngfor

tengo una función llamada agregarAlimento que introduce un objeto en 1 array llamado arrAlimentos. De este array, realizo una copia de cada elemento y lo introduzco en el array llamado desayuno así lo puedo arrastrar a la ingesta que desee (desayuno, comida o cena).

Quisiera poder **eliminar un item (alimento) del desayuno por ejemplo y que a la vez se elimine del array arrAlimentos**. Para ello había pensado en crear una función llamada eliminar que la puedo llamar desde el evento (click) pero no sé cómo obtener el parámetro necesario (indexArralimentos):

```
eliminar (indexArralimentos)
{
this.arrAlimentos.splice(indexArralimentos, 1);
}
```

Adjunto mi código subido al editor online:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-material-xmjmxu

Os agradezco mucho de antemano vuestra atención, un cordial saludo.

PD: Al fin pude solucionarlo gracias al compañero, de la siguiente manera:

añadiendo la siguiente propiedad cuando agrego un alimento:
idUnico: uuid.v4()
(lo que genera un id único por cada elemento de la matriz introducida)

```
 eliminar (item) {
    

    const searchId = (element) => element.idUnico === item.idUnico;

    const indexArralimentos = this.arrAlimentos.findIndex(searchId);

    this.arrAlimentos.splice(indexArralimentos, 1);

    
    this.addPesoAlimento();
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías generar un id único para cada elemento cuando lo creas, y cuando lo vas a eliminar lo buscas también en el arreglo de alimentos. Puedes usar la librería uuid para hacerlo:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

```js
import * as uuid from 'uuid';

const idUnico = uuid.v4();
```

Comment: Gracias pude implementar tu solución, he puesto la posible solución en el post, un cordial saludo.